# ProductsImport Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to import both the price.xls and the price.xls file.

```
  $productsArray = Excel::toArray(new ProductsImport(), 'fiyat.xls');
    $products = $productsArray[0];

    $dbProducts = [];
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        if ($key > 1 && $value[5] != '' && $value[6] != '' && $value[7] != ''){

            $sellPrice = strval($value[3]);
            $merchantId = $value[5];
            $productId = $value[6];
            $priceId = $value[7];
```

I am writing like this, it doesn't work

```
  $productsArray = Excel::toArray(new ProductsImport(), 'price.xls', 'price1.xls');
```

Comment: You can try with two sheets in same excel

Comment: I tried it didn't happen

Comment: This is the structure of toArray function 
`public function toArray($import, $filePath, string $disk = null, string $readerType = null): array` which shows that third parameter is to specify disk, not another file. To import multiple sheets please do it as explained in the docs https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html